# Expected Value of $Z = min(X, M)$ where M is a constant

Tags: probability

> Let $X \sim Geometric(p)$, and let $M > 0$ be a positive integer. Determine the expected value of $Z = min(X, M)$.

I have done similar exercises where $M$ is a random variable, but not a constant. I don't know how to proceed here, and therefore have no work to show. Hints are very welcome although It would be nice to see more or less of a complete solution for a case like this.

Thank you.

Comment: Simply calculate $E(Z)=\sum_j \min(j,M)p(j)$, where $p$ is the pmf of $X$.

Comment: yes, but how to calculate the $min(j, M)$ part?

Comment: $\min(j,M)=j$ if $j<M$ and equals $M$ if $j\ge M$. So break the sum accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
EZ=EXI(X<M)+EMI(X\geq M)\tag{0}
$$
where $I$ is the indicator function since $Z=X$ if $X<M$ and $Z=M$ if $X\geq M$. But
$$
EMI(X\geq M)=MP(X\geq M)\tag{1}
$$
and
$$
EXI(X<M)=\sum_{k=0}^{M-1}kP(X=k).\tag{2}
$$
Since $X$ is geometric we can compute, $(1)$ and $(2)$ and hence $(0)$. I leave this computation to you.